# How to query relational document in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

There are two collections.

Collection - **PostedBy**

```
{
    _id: "2461177814122722",
    name : "Nur"
    location: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [ 90.341044,  23.787105 ]
    }
}
```

Collection - **Posts**

```
{
    _id: "5e7447336da7300a1cb64c51",
    model: asus,
    postedBy : "2461177814122722",
    price : 1255   
}
```

How can I query like so?

```
posts.find({
  postedBy: {
    location: {
      $near: [-74, 40],
      $maxDistance: 10
    }
  }
});
```

I want to query by this document below. But how can I query relational document in mongoose?

```
{
  _id: "5e7447336da7300a1cb64c51",
  model: asus,
  postedBy: {
    name: "Nur",
    location: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [90.341044, 23.787105]
    }
  },
  price: 1255
};
```

Comment: The coordinates have to be number values, not strings.

Comment: ok. But How can I query relational document ?

Comment: - use aggregation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/ - use look up aggregation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to create a 2d Index:

```
db.PostedBy.createIndex({ location: "2dsphere" })
```

Then you can run an aggregation like this:

```
db.PostedBy.aggregate([
   {
      $geoNear: {
         near: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [-74, 40]
         },
         distanceField: "distance",
         //maxDistance: 20000, // max. Distance in Meters
         spherical: true
      }
   },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "posts",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "postedBy",
            as: "posts"
         }
   },
   {
      $project: {
         model: "$posts.model",
         price: "$posts.price",
         postedBy: { name: "$name", location: "$location" }
      }
   }
])
```

Note, `[-74, 40]` to `[90.341044, 23.787105]` is more than 10'000 km, verify your input values.

Values of `price` and `model` are returned as array, because you may have more than one post for each "PostedBy". If you like to get single element then append `{ $set: { model: { $arrayElemAt: ["$model", 0] } } }` or `{ $unwind: "$model" }`, resp. `price`